# Up-Navigation Arrow disappeared after implementing Navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

After I implemented a Navigation Drawer my up Arrow for up Navigation disappeared.

```
mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.navList);
    addDrawerItems();
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    });
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.project_drawer);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, android.R.color.transparent, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            mSlideState = true;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            mSlideState = false;
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I've set the parentActivity in AndroidManifest too:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/projects"
        android:icon="@android:color/transparent"
        android:parentActivityName=".Activity1">
```

Does it have to do with the `android.R.color.transparent` in the `ActionBarDrawerToogle`?

Note: I set a MenuItem to open/close the Navigation Drawer. THats the reason why I set `android.R.color.transparent`.

Now just the Activity label appears.

What did I do wrong?

Kind Regards!

Comment: "Does it have to do with the android.R.color.transparent in the ActionBarDrawerToogle?" - Most likely. Everything else looks right. Why are you setting to transparent anyway?

Comment: because I set a menuitem in the actionbar to open/close the navigation drawer. Thats why I dont want any icon in the left side of the ActionBar.

Comment: It sounds like you don't need the `ActionBarDrawerToogle` at all, then. You can just create a straight `DrawerListener` to handle the `onDrawerOpened()` and `onDrawerClosed()` methods.

Comment: Oh hell yes! I removed the Code with ´ActionBarDrawerToggle` and now it works like I want! Thank you!!!